# How do you make "Quick Links" web part links open in same tab/window (for lists and document libraries)?

Tags: quick-links

I would like my "Quick LINKS" web part links to open in the same tab/window just as the "Quick LAUNCH" navigation bar links open in the same tab/window.
I have found that "Pages" in my site linked to quick link web part open in the same tab/window. Lists and libraries open in a new tab.

This is a team site, classic template, using modern experience.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it this issue you are facing : https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/17978740-stop-opening-links-in-new-tab-in-modern-pages

In that case it seems like you will have to wait for Microsoft to fix it.

On a classic page this could be fixed by injecting a js script, but that is not an option on modern pages :-(

Comment: Yes. The situation with lots and lots of tabs! And it sounds similar but not exactly so I'm going to clarify with some more details and a screen shot. It is a classic template site. The page is a modern page with quick links web part and it is also our home page. Modern pages from the quick links open within the same window. Lists and libraries created originally in classic (now modern experience) open in new tabs. Not sure any of that changes anything, but wanted to clarify before I marked the question as answered and I wait for microsoft to fix it! :-)